# Linear Regression for multi variable not working as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

When I use this code for Single variable Linear regression, the theta is being evaluated correctly but when on the multi variable it is giving weird output for theta.

I am trying to convert my octave code, that I wrote when I took Andrew Ng's course.

This is the main calling file:

```
m = data.shape[0]

a = np.array(data[0])
a.shape = (m,1)
b = np.array(data[1])
b.shape = (m, 1)
x = np.append(a, b, axis=1)
y = np.array(data[2])

lr = LR.LinearRegression()
[X, mu, sigma] = lr.featureNormalize(x)
z = np.ones((m, 1), dtype=float)
X = np.append(z, X, axis=1)
alpha = 0.01
num_iters = 400
theta = np.zeros(shape=(3,1))
[theta, J_history] = lr.gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
print(theta)
```

And here are the contents of class :

```
class LinearRegression:
    def featureNormalize(self, data):#this normalizes the features
        data = np.array(data)
        x_norm = data
        mu = np.zeros(shape=(1, data.shape[1]))#creates mu vector filled with zeros
        sigma = np.zeros(shape=(1, data.shape[1]))

        for i in range(0, data.shape[1]):
            mu[0, i] = np.mean(data[:, i])
            sigma[0, i] = np.std(data[:, i])

        for i in range(0, data.shape[1]):
            x_norm[:, i] = np.subtract(x_norm[:, i], mu[0, i])
            x_norm[:, i] = np.divide(x_norm[:, i], sigma[0, i])

        return [x_norm, mu, sigma]

    def gradientDescent(self, X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
        m = y.shape[0]
        J_history = np.zeros(shape=(num_iters, 1))

        for i in range(0, num_iters):
            predictions = X.dot(theta) # X is 47*3 theta is 3*1 predictions is 47*1
            theta = np.subtract(theta , (alpha / m) * np.transpose((np.transpose(np.subtract(predictions ,y))).dot(X))) #1*97 into 97*3
            J_history[i] = self.computeCost(X, y, theta)
        return [theta, J_history]

    def computeCost(self, X, y, theta):
        warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
        m = X.shape[0]
        J = 0
        predictions = X.dot(theta)
        sqrErrors = np.power(predictions - y, 2)
        J = 1 / (2 * m) * np.sum(sqrErrors)
        return J
```

I expected a theta that'll be a 3*1 matrix. According to Andrew's course my octave implementation was producing a theta

```
334302.063993 
 100087.116006 
 3673.548451
```

But in python implementation I am getting very weird output:

```
[[384596.12996714 317274.97693463 354878.64955708 223121.53576488
  519238.43603216 288423.05420641 302849.01557052 191383.45903309
  203886.92061274 233219.70871976 230814.42009498 333720.57288972
  317370.18827964 673115.35724932 249953.82390212 432682.6678475
  288423.05420641 192249.97844569 480863.45534211 576076.72380674
  243221.70859887 245241.34318985 233604.4010228  249953.82390212
  551937.2817908  240336.51632605 446723.93690857 451051.7253178
  456822.10986344 288423.05420641 336509.59208678 163398.05571747
  302849.01557052 557707.6...................... this goes on for long
```

The same code is working absolutely fine in Single Variable dataset. It is also working fine in the octave but seems like I am missing some point for 2+ hours now. Happy to get your help.

Comment: Did it work for you or should I dive more into it?

Comment: @ericj I was able to figure it out. Seems like .dot should be replaced with @. as that .dot is creating a lot of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in gradientDescent the following second line of the for loop:

```
theta=theta-(alpha/m)*X.T.dot(X.dot(theta)-y)
```

Also, if you want to add a column of ones, it is easier to do like so:

```
np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),data]
```